# Having trouble injecting my Spring security user into my controller

Tags: spring, security, dependency-injection

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE with Spring Security 3.1.  I want to inject my Spring user (i.e. the user who is currently logged in) into a controller.  I want to do this as opposed to using

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

because it allows me to test the controller more easily with JUnit.  However, I'm having a problem with my current setup.  My question is, what is the correct way to inject my user (per request) into my controller?  In my application context file, I have ...

```
<bean id="userDetails" class="com.myco.eventmaven.security.SecurityHolder" factory-method="getUserDetails" scope="request">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

where I define my factory class as ...

```
public class SecurityHolder {

@Autowired
private static UserService userService;

public static MyUserDetails getUserDetails() {
    final Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (a == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        final MyUserDetails reg = (MyUserDetails) a.getPrincipal();
        final int userId = reg.getId();
        final MyUserDetails foundUser = userService.findUserById(userId);
        return foundUser;
    } // if
}   // getUserDetails

}
```

but the factory class repeatedly dies because "userService" fails to get autowired (the value is always null).  I'm looking for a better way to do all this that can easily also integrate into my JUnit test.  Any ideas?

**Edit**: Here's the JUnit test I'm looking to work with ...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:src/test/resources/testApplicationContext.xml" })
public class UserEventFeedsControllerTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

private MockHttpServletRequest request;
private MockHttpServletResponse response;
...
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    ...
    request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
}
...
@Test
public void testSubmitUserEventFeedsForm() throws Exception {
    request.setRequestURI("/eventfeeds.jsp");
    request.setMethod("POST");
    final List<EventFeed> allEventFeeds = getAllEventFeeds();
    request.setParameter("userEventFeeds", allEventFeeds.get(0).getId().toString());

    final Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
    final ModelAndView mav = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);

    assertViewName(mav, "user/eventfeeds");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot autowire `static` fields. There are some workarounds, but I don't want to show them to you...

There are plenty of ways to access current user in an easier and more elegant matter:

- Inject `Principal` to your controller (see [When using Spring Security, what is the proper way to obtain current username (i.e. SecurityContext) information in a bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562)):

  ```
  public ModelAndView showResults(final HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
    final String currentUser = principal.getName();
    UserDetails ud = ((Authentication)principal).getPrincipal()
  ```
- Develop your custom [facade](/questions/tagged/facade) over `SecurityContext`
- Replace built-in `contextHolderStrategy` in `SecurityContextHolder` for the purpose of testing

## See also

- [How to get active user's UserDetails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545)
- [Spring 3 MVC Controller integration test - inject Principal into method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990931)

Comment: Regarding your first suggestion, how do I inject the Principal object in my JUnit test using the Spring4JUnitRunner class?  I have added a code example illustrating how I'm running my Junit test.

Comment: I couldn't find an elegant way of getting from my original UserDetails object to a Principal object so I had to create a test class that extended my original UserDetails object and implemented Principal.  I injected that test class into the request per your link and I was good to go.

Comment: You can't use static because you shouldn't. Ever. Really.